# content text appears under css block instead of wrapping arround

Tags: css

My content text is displayed under content div. Inside that div I have floated div block which have menu content with links.

Problem is that my content text appears under menu div block and I want to force content text to break arround menu block.

Live example is heee
http://jsfiddle.net/qYcWc/

```
#content {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 570px;    
}
#content .subLinks {
    background-color:gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 330px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
}

<div id="content">                    
    <div class="subLinks">
    <ul class="subLinksMenu">
        <li><a title="LinkOne" href="/">LinkOne</a></li>
        <li><a title="LinkTwo" href="/">LinkTwo</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>                    
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty pretty messy CSS, will take on point by point, if you don't care to read, here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qYcWc/3/) for you

1) `position: absolute;` is a culprit here, when you use `position: absolute;` the div flows out of document flow and hence your div has no idea to wrap around the box.

2) Why use `display: inline;` and `float: left;` together?

3) Use of explicit margins, not required!

4) Always wrap text inside an element, say `p` for semantic meaning, it says yes, the text is a paragraph

[**Easy Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qYcWc/6/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest floating your `subLinks` to the right. This will let the content text wrap around it:

```
#content .subLinks {
    background-color:gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:0px 0px 15px 15px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qYcWc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qYcWc/5/

Try simplifying your solution:

```
#content {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 570px;
}

.subLinks {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```